# How to pass data from mapStateToProps to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-props

This is my component:

```
export default const NotesComponent = () => {
  return notesList.map((noteProps) => (
    <NewsCard {...notesProps} key={notesProps.id} />
  ))
}
```

Here is the place where i use this component:

```
const Notes = (props: NotesProps) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <NotesComponent />
    </Container>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  notesData: state.notes.notesData,
})
// and other code so mapStateToProps is working correctly
```

I don't know how to pass `notesData` to `NotesComponent`, so the `NewsCard` can read the data.

Comment: @Iver Why would you connect Notes to redux state and then never use it in the component?

Comment: The component need to be clean because i am using it on other places too, so i need to reuse the component and give the data out of the component document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) high-order-function from react-redux and export the returned component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// Redux state data notesData will be available in props
const NotesComponent = ({notesData}) => { 
  return notesData.map((noteProps) => (
    <NewsCard {...noteProps} key={noteProps.id} />
  ))
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  notesData: state.notes.notesData,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NotesComponent)
```

Or, as `NotesComponent` is a function component, you can use react-hook [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) instead of using `connect` to read redux data:

```
// in a function component
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
...
const notesData = useSelector((state) => state.notes.notesData)
```

#### Edit:

You can also connect parent component i.e. `Notes` with Redux and pass data to `NotesComponent` in props (to make `NotesComponent` a dumb or reusable component):

```
interface NotesProps {
  notesData: write_your_type[]
  // ...
}

const Notes = (props: NotesProps) => {
  const { notesData } = props
  return (
    <Container>
      <NotesComponent data={notesData} />
    </Container>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  notesData: state.notes.notesData,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Notes) 
// it now exports enhanced (with redux data in props) Notes component
```

And, `NotesComponent`:

```
export default const NotesComponent = ({data}) => { 
  return data.map((item) => (
    <NewsCard {...item} key={item.id} />
  ))
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what im looking for.